# Algorithm reference

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

This is a trivial question  - but something I always miss in the day-to-day programming.
Is there a gook lookup reference available for the common algorithms that we usually face in our everyday programming  - sorting,sequences,graphs.
The emphasis is more on the applicability and pseudocode ,rather than the mathematical proofs(which I find is what books tend to stress on).
The idea is to keep a ready reference,as and when we need to resort to one of these algorithms into our respective development project and languages.

Comment: Wikipedia is good, but I think the OP wants a list so he can refer to them all at once too.

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

[List of algorithms@Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms)